# Wordpress not working when including jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

If I include a later version of jQuery in Wordpress things like the Widgets page is no longer working. When I try to click on the down arrow in a specific widget to update it it doesn't show its settings.

```
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_jquery_script', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_jquery-ui_script', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_flexslider_script', plugins_url('/js/ecom-jquery.flexslider.js', __FILE__)); 
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_admin_script', plugins_url('/js/ecom-main.js', __FILE__));
```

But when I comment out jquery and other scripts that depends on it the widgets page will work.

I've already tried looking for solutions but the common solution is making jquery no conflict:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

But this doesn't work because simply including a newer version of jquery will make scripts that depends on the older version of jquery to not work. Please help.

Deregister script doesn't work either since wordpress simply refuses to work if a newer version of jquery is used:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

Comment: Could you try to include the following plugin http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/? If the older scripts depending on jQuery old version are causing the issue this could help.

Comment: so, you need the older jquery version working on the admin page, but for the theme you need a newer?

Comment: I'm writing a wordpress plugin and some interactions(both the admin and the public) needs the newer version of jquery to work.

Comment: Have you tried to include it with simply a php require?

Comment: @Zekth: That's not a good advice ;)

Comment: It's just to test the .js itself and its interaction with the rest of the theme. I'm not meaning it's good for production.

Comment: @Zekth require/include from a remote URL is not allowed in PHP, even if that URL is actually local, maybe a hook is better for this ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy : I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure they are few tricks you can do to get this work, but I think the best (for version compatibilities) is to include the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate). This plugin provides two essential facilities:

1. It re-enables deprecated features so your v1.8-compatible code will work again
2. It logs warnings to the developer console when deprecated features are used, so you should find it easier to fix issues.

The migrate plugin should be loaded immediately after jQuery, e.g.

```
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_jquery_script', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('ecom_jquery_mig_script', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js');
```

However, you should take a look of the [changelog](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9) of the last jQuery version.

**NOTE:** The `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` function is working, but you need to register again with the same name (jquery) and then enqueue like this:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery')
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js'); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```